# Pentaho javacriot code variable object

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to navigate my object with the response of my rest client method, this response is theoretically a JSON Object such that.

```
{"457": {"2": {"value": "53.8", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "3": {"value": "21.9", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "4": {"value": "255.0", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "21": {"value": "996.0", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "1": {"value": "4.15", " timestamp ": 1534257707}," 17 ": {" value ":" 156.99062499999997 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 5 ": {" value ":" 37.667 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 6 ": {"value": "28.900000000000002", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "8": {"value": "4.28", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "15": {"value": "0.83", " timestamp ": 1534257707}," 10 ": {" value ":" 19.31 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 22 ": {" value ":" 0.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 23 ": {"value": "0.0", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "24": {"value": "0.0", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "26": {"value": "0.0", " timestamp ": 1534257707}," 653 ": {" value ":" 0.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 657 ": {" value ":" - 98.0 "," timestamp ": 1518420299}," 43 " : {"value": "11.824136243472958", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "42": {"value": "326.54049999999995", "timestamp": 1534257707}}}
```

I have created a component in JavaScript to process this data:

This is my code in java script and it works correctly, since I have tried it programming it in another environment.

```
var key = Object.keys (data) [0];
var finalobj = {};
    for (var and in data [key]) {
    finalobj [e] = {
    type: "float"
    , value: parseFloat (data [key] [e] .value)
    , metadata: {
    timestamp: {
    value: parseInt (data [key] [e] .timestamp)
    , type: "Integer"
    }
    }
    };
    }
```

The problem is that if I assign to the field it dates the value of my answer like this:

```
var data = result_ult_dat;
```

When I throw the code it does not work, but if I manually assign the code to it, if it works correctly, what is the problem ?, I do not understand it, the value of result_ult_dat is the same as the one that I copied, it has to be transforming or something like this:

```
var data = {"457": {"2": {"value": "53.8", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "3": {"value": "21.9", "timestamp": 1534257707}, " 4 ": {" value ":" 255.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 21 ": {" value ":" 996.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 1 ": {" value ":" 4.15 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 17 ": {" value ":" 156.99062499999997 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 5 ": {" value ":" 37.667 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 6 ": {" value ":" 28.900000000000002 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 8 ": {" value ":" 4.28 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 15 ": {" value ":" 0.83 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 10 ": {" value ":" 19.31 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 22 ": {" value ":" 0.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 23 ": {" value ":" 0.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 24 ": {" value ":" 0.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 26 ": {" value ":" 0.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 653 ": {" value ":" 0.0 "," timestamp ": 1534257707}," 657 ": {" value ":" - 98.0 "," timestamp ": 1518420299}, "43": {"value": "11.824136243472958", "timestamp": 1534257707}, "42": {"value": "326.54049999999995", "timestamp": 1534257707}}};
```

How can I fix the problem.

My complete code is this:

[image: Pentaho codigo]

Thank you very much.

**Edit01**

This is my complete design, as you can see the value of data is the same as the response of my http client.

[image: Complego1]

answer if I pass it by variable

[image: String]

the funny thing is that JSONOutPut is {} when it would have to be the for transformation.

[image: completo]

And when I try to put as such the answer in the data variable if it works, look.

[image: Funciona]

I do not understand why

Comment: Where is the problem? That some of the fields have spaces `(" 4 ": {" value ":" 255.0 "...)` or that you cannot get the value of `data` in a field ?

Comment: the problem is JsonOutput I returned {}, when I would have to return a transformation, if instead I assign data = {xxxx ...} by hand as I put up if I returned information, but doing so by the variable does not work data = result_ult_dat .

The strange thing is that if I call data = result_ult_dat and show data if it has the information of http.

Comment: It gives the impression that the variable is not loaded until the complete code is finished.

since if I put the information at hand if it does everything right.

Comment: Did you add the variable JsonOutput (with type String) in the small table at the bottom of the step window?

Comment: I edit the post and I show you my full board in the lower table.

Also show the two answers as I have commented with the value of the answer and with the added value to full.

I'm desperate I do not know what else to try, it seems that the value recovers at the end.

Comment: So, if I do understand, you get the correct `JsonOutput` when you use `data={"457"...}` but is empty when you use `data=result_utl_data`. Is that the problem?

Comment: yes, this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding this to my javascript code and working with object

```
var object = JSON.parse (result_ult_dat);
```